# JMS queue with Apache Artemis, how to only retrieve the last message in the queue

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I'm currently using Artemis ActiveMQ 2.2.0 and with the queue, I was able to send and receive message without any issue. However, I would like to find out how the receiver could only retrieve the last message if there are multiple messages in the queue? Is there any special queue I should use? Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to tell a consumer to consume the *last* message in a queue. A queue's fundamental semantics are first-in-first-out (i.e. FIFO) so they aren't designed for consuming the last message. However, if you have some flexibility in your producers and consumers you can get essentially the same behavior.

I would recommend you take advantage of the last-value queue. It's a special type of queue where messages with the same "last-value" message property automatically replace older messages in the queue with that same property so that the only message with that property in the queue is the "last" one that was sent.

Your producer would need to set the "last-value" property on the message and then the consumer would use a selector with this same property. In this way the consumer will always get the most recent message that was sent regardless of how many other messages have been sent to the queue.

You can see this in action in the last-value example shipped with the broker in `examples/features/standard/last-value-queue`. You can also [browse it online](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/last-value-queue) if you like.

You can read more about it in the [Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/last-value-queues.html).

Comment: last-value queue is different from getting the last message out of a queue. Last-value queue still holds multiple messages, but only the latest for each specified key. The question is how to get the last message out of a queue regardless of key. If I want a queue of events for state of a device when I connect I want to know the last message, but not have to read the whole queue. You proposed solution doesn't really have any relevance to the problem.

Comment: The OP specifically asked, "Is there any special queue I should use?" The answer to that question is, "You can use a last-value queue." My answer already states that one needs to use a special "last-value" message property. If one combines that with a consumer using a selector with that same last-value property then the consumer will always get the last message sent. This is a perfectly viable & relevant solution to the OP's problem, although it's not a 100% direct solution. It's also worth noting that the OP didn't qualify his question with "regardless of key." I'll update to clarify a bit.

Comment: I think you should add the portion about consuming with a selector. I don't think it's entirely clear that you're suggesting that. Also I wouldn't say this is typically the use of a last-value queue. Last-value queue is more so like trying to keep track of the latest stock price. You'll have several stock prices in a single topic but only latest for each. Similarly you could have a ring queue of size one and then the only message you'll ever have is the latest and you can use a QueueBrowser to get the last message quickly. Thing is you are now removing old messages which you might not want.

Comment: I added details about using a selector on the consumer. Stock-prices are the quintessential last-value queue use-case (which is what the linked example demonstrates). However, in my opinion the OP doesn't really provide enough details to know whether or not a last-value queue will be a good fit or not.

Comment: As you note, a ring-queue is also a potential solution. However, I wrote my original answer is September 2017, and I didn't [implement ring queues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2457) until August 2019.

Comment: Fair enough. I think honestly the best solution would probably be to just read backwards from the last item in the queue but I'm fairly certain that's not really possible in an efficient manner. I agree, the question could probably be more detailed.

Comment: If reading the queue backwards was possible then I would certainly agree that would likely be a better solution but, as you suspect, it's not. A queue is FIFO, but what you're describing is essentially a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Using JMS you can only browse the queue till the last message, get JMSMessageID of the last message and then pull it out from the queue using selector by JMSMessageID.